# Material3 Theme Builder - can't get all colors from preview

Tags: android, android-theme, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3, android-color

So I'm trying to use the following link to build theme for an app:

https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom

But I can't figure out the following color of the container:

[image]

It's not listed anywhere and I'm trying to set the same color for cards in my app.

Does anybody know?

**upd**: it looks something like `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(1.dp)` but still the color code is a little bit different, `1.dp` is the closest one to get the similar color, but mb it's actually the right answer, just a little difference between implementation of the web preview and a real app with jetpack Compose Material 3

Answer (score 0):

Actually, yeah, it should be `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(1.dp)`.

I tried different colors on the web site and then in my app and finally they matched - I have been using "Screen ColorPicker (HEX)" software for Windows to get code from web site and Jetpack Compose previews

Answer (score 0):

If you used the theme generated from the website, the Card colour is using the colour defined by `md_theme_light_surfaceVariant` or `md_theme_dark_surfaceVariant` for dark mode.

From material theme it's `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant`

Comment: yes, I downloaded archive, but it's not surfaceVariant, it's totally different color

Comment: So the colour in the preview on the web, doesn't match the colour it generates for `surfaceVariant`, is that the issue? If you create a composable and just add a basic `Card`, you can change `surfaceVariant` values and the background colour will change, this is definitely the default.

Comment: it's `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(1.dp)`, the color of the container from the screenshot I provided is not listed anywhere, not on the web page preview of color list, not at the achieve in Color.kt. Just check it yourself

Comment: It's because the website is using the alpha channel, whereas the theme colours are solid colours. Weird that they did it that way, but it's probably to simplify the light/dark switching (e.g. the theme colours in the CSS aren't changed). If you want the colour on the website then just grab the RGB values of it and update `surfaceVariant` value in your theme and all your cards will be the colour you want. It looks like a completely different colour because it uses 5% alpha (hence is strongly influenced by the background), I assume it was intended to be a very close match.

Comment: Also, if you use `Surface`, then the elevated colours are applied automatically.